# How can I fix my vista PCs screen resolution and refresh rate

Tags: windows-vista, resolution, hdmi, hdtv, refresh-rate

I have a media PC running media portal hooked up to my HDTV via HDMI. The TV is a couple of years old now, so only supports 1080i, which is 1920x1080@25Hz. I've got it connected to my PC via a HDMI compatible AV receiver.

If I power up the amp (wait for it to boot fully) followed by the TV| and finally the PC, all is well and I get a picture. If I deviate from that sequence, or don't wait for the amp to power up fully, or even switch the amp to another video input (for example, my PS3). The PC sees this and defaults the screen resolution/refresh rate to 1920x1080@60Hz. So, I end up with a blank screen.

To fix this I have to use UltraVNC from a PC and change the refresh rate back to 25Hz.

So, is there a way to turn off that auto detection, or to manually define what resolution/refresh rates the monitor can do.

I'm using the on-board Radeon 3200 video and do not have any of the AMD software installed as it seems to cause problems with video playback. So, I'm looking for a native vista fix, or possible some 3rd party software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon the answer on the [MediaPortal](http://www.team-mediaportal.com/) forum [here](http://forum.team-mediaportal.com/general-62/hdmi-problem-solved-83434/#post628498).

The answer is to turn off the "Ati External Event Utility" service, this has stopped the PC from seeing the monitor has "gone" when I turn off the TV or switch the amp to another HDMI input and therefore doesn't set the resolution back to 1080p 60Hz

Problem solved :D

Answer (score 0):

HDMI carries information over the wire on the settings the output can support. In this case, I highly suspect the AV box is sending the info it can support 1080@60hz thus your PC is defaulting to that settings.

It is a non-optimal solution to connect your PC to the HDMI AV receiver, and then passthrough to the TV. I suggest you get a [cheap HDMI switcher](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001JTQUYG) that should not give you any further trouble.

Comment: I used to do just that, and had exactly the same problem. It would still default to the wrong refresh rate.

Comment: Also, I am using my amp in conjunction with a HDMI splitter so I can view any source on either my TV or projector. Oh, and the amp up-scales analog sources to HDMI too.

I was really looking for some way to lock the refresh rate of the PC to 1920x1080@25Hz, as my projector can handle that. But my TV cannot handle anything else!